# query using Foreign Key property or navigation property? EF 4.1

Tags: c#, query-optimization, entity-framework-4.1

I'm mapping some POCO classes to an existing database with several lookup tables and I was wondering what would be the most efficient or recommended way to proceed.

Let's say there's an `Employee` model class that maps to an Employee table:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set }

    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleID { get; set }
    public virtual EmployeeRole Role { get; set }
}
```

and the `EmployeeRole` class/table looks like:

```
public class EmployeeRole
{
    public int ID { get; set } // For instance: 1
    public string Description { get; set } // for instance: Manager
}
```

I know I don't need to explicitly declare the Foreign Key `RoleID`, but I actually have to perform quite an amount of queries that depend on an `Employee` having the `EmployeeRole` of "Manager".

Now the question is, what is better in terms of combining efficiency, code readability and "data independence"?
Assuming `employees` is an `IQueryable` just pulled from a repository:

1. `employees.Where(e => e.RoleID == 1);`
2. `employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeRole.ID == 1);`
3. `employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeRole.Description == "Manager");`

2 and 3 have the disadvantage of having to lazy-load the navigation property, but 1 has the disadvantage that `RoleID == 1` is rather meaningless and bound to the current state of the database.

How should I proceed? Is there an option 4?

Comment: Just one note to your sentence "*2 and 3 have the disadvantage of having to lazy-load the navigation property*". I don't think that the `EmployeeRole` nav. property is lazily loaded. You don't access a concrete instance of an `Employee` object in your query, but you are just phrasing an `Expression` which is later translated into SQL. There is no lazy loading involved. Having a foreign key property is not that interesting for read operations (using the ID of the nav. prop. does the same, as the answer below proves), it's more important for updates/inserts. 1 and 2 are really the same.

Comment: @Slauma - You're right, thanks. I actually realised that when J. Tihon posted the Trace results on his answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that, all 3 queries would yield similar results. At least 1 and 2 should produce the same SQL. You can see the generated SQL statement by calling "ToTraceString" on the ObjectSet instance (I would have to look this up, might be hidden somewhere else).

-- Edit
I've recreated your model and found out that the following queries were used (SQL Server). You have to cast the query to System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery, which provides the ToTraceString() method.

```
employees.Where(e => e.RoleID == 1);
employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeRole.ID == 1);

// Both result in:
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[RoleId]
```

and

```
employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeRole.Description == "Manager");

SELECT  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], [Extent1].[RoleId] AS [RoleId]
FROM  [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Roles] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[RoleId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE N'Manager' = [Extent2].[Name]
```

Comment: Tihon - Cool, thanks and +1 for that. I didn't know EF was smart enough to generate the same query for options 1 and 2. Makes sense on hindsight though. This sort of rules out option 3 as well. Still, it's a pity that `RoleID == 1` is such meaningless code... Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. Sure you never know if "1" is actually the ID of the Role "Manager", but you could always query the Manager-ID before you perform all related queries.

Comment: I 'm just trying to see if there's a perfect solution in this case, one that will hit the db as little as possible while being as readable and maintainable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I introduced the concept of "flags" in my tables with great success. For example if you know what you may often query for managers, add a bit to the table called 
"Manager", and in your code simply do `e.EmployeeRole.Manager` and your done. Strongly typed and  has real business meaning.